# NullPointerException in Neo4j ETL tool

Tags: neo4j

I want migrate my MySQL database to neo4j. When I try to import the data into a neo4j DB with the help of the neo4j ETL tool:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\ADMIN.Neo4jDesktop\graphApps_global\neo4j-etl-ui/dist/neo4j-etl.jar" org.neo4j.etl.NeoIntegrationCli export --mapping-file "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp/mysql_testdb_testdb_mapping.json"
  --rdbms:password "" --rdbms:user "root" --rdbms:url "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useCursorFetch=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"
  --options-file "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp/import-tool-options.json" --using "cypher:fromSQL" --unwind-batch-size 1000 --tx-batch-size 10000
  --neo4j:database-name ecomm --neo4j:url "bolt://localhost:7687" --neo4j:user "neo4j" --neo4j:password "123"
```

I get this error:

```
Illegal command (NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()" because "this.debug" is null)
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying an empty RDBMS password:

```
--rdbms:password ""
```

You should specify the actual password instead.